# how can show a html table row by row using php

Tags: php, html

this is my code to display a html table using php :

```
echo "<table border='1'>";
        for ($r =0; $r < $rows; $r++){
             echo'<tr>';
             echo "<th> Etat".$r."</th>";
             for ($c = 0; $c < $rows; $c++){
                 echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="'.$r.''.$c.'" placeholder="nb d etat" /></td>';
               }
                 if ($c==$rows) {
            ECHO '<td><input type="number" name="'.$r.''.$c.'" placeholder="etat" /></td>';
          }
           echo '</tr>'; // close tr tag her
        }
echo "</table>";
```

and this is the php file to recuperate data

```
 foreach ($p as $k => $v) {
 if ($v=="on") {
    # code...
     $a= "X$k \n";
     echo $a;
 }

else {
    $b="$v \n";
    echo $b;
}

}
```

and this is the result :

```
X00 
X02 
12 
X10 
X11 
21 
X22 
17
```

the objective is :
if the checkbox checked recupere the keys of the same row like this :

`(X00+X01+X02 .......etc)`

follows recupere the value (input in the last column of the table ) ex:12
finally a want to traduce each row like this :

```
12(X00+X02)
21(X10+X11)
17(X22)
```

[i want just to display this table like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbrwT.png)

please help me to do this 
and thanks in advance

Comment: use a different name for the last column's checkbox

Comment: how can i know the last column's checkbox ?  because it is a dynamic html table generated with php ( the number of rows is entered by a user )

Comment: you are setting the name to .$r.''.$c (btw don't need the empty string in the middle), set the name for the last one to something else (you are adding it separately anyway, in the if statement)

Comment: i would have written an answer, for me its hard to understand your question

if you edit your question please use something meaningful in place of X00 X01 or $param in place of $p
a

Comment: I edit my question you can see the image I added to  understand

Comment: use name="'.$r.'['.$c.']" instead of name="'.$r.''.$c.'". It will wrap all c with r.